# I want to know if we did enter an trade the last 5 candels

Tags: pine-script, trading

I have  some conditions that needs to be true to enter a trade.
But, this conditions can be fullfilled for multiple candels in a row.
How can I look back 5 candels and see if a trade was entred, then I don't want to enter a new possition.

I know the `pyramiding=1` can be used to only enter one trade, but this is not the solution I'm looking for. I want to be able to keep enter the trade but not with the candels so close together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this condition to your entry condition:

```
cond = barssince(change(strategy.position_size)) > 5
```

Comment: Thanks @PineCoders-LucF. It works perfect! Is it the same line of code for SHORT positions?

Comment: To detect shorts only, would need: `barssince(change(strategy.position_size) < 0) > 5`

Comment: Thank you! You have really helpt me. I still have one problem tho.. When i add the barssince on buy condition it works.. But when I add it to my sell condition, everything stops working. So only `BuySignal = Macd1x > 0 and Macd4x > 0 and barssince(change(strategy.position_size)) > 5` is working, but when I add the barssince to my sell, everything stops working. No error for the script tho...

`BuySignal = Macd1x > 0 and Macd4x > 0 and barssince(change(strategy.position_size)) > 5
SellSignal = Macd1x < 0 and Macd4x < 0 and barssince(change(strategy.position_size)) > 5`

Comment: Sry but without compilable code reproducing your problem, it's pretty difficult to help. You should be using `barssince(change(strategy.position_size) < 0) > 5` to detect short entries (but it will also detect long exits if some occur), and  `barssince(change(strategy.position_size) > 0) > 5` to detect long entries, with the same, opposite caveat. Can't do more without code.

Comment: I post my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63945371/entry-is-not-working-when-using-barssincechangestrategy-position-size-10 
Would be awesome if you could take a look @PineCoders-LucF