# Entry is not working when using barssince(change(strategy.position_size)) > 10

Tags: pine-script, trading

I have a wierd problem in my script.

This is working code:

```
//@version=4
strategy("Test script", overlay=true, pyramiding=100)
process_orders_on_close=true

// FACTOR 1X MACD
fastMA = round(12*1)
slowMA = round(26*1)
signal = round(9*1)
[Macd1x,_,Hist] = macd(close[0], fastMA, slowMA, signal)

// FACTOR 4X MACD
fastMA4x = round(12*4)
slowMA4x = round(26*4)
signal4x = round(9*4)
[Macd4x,_,_] = macd(close[0], fastMA4x, slowMA4x, signal4x)

// TRADE CONDITIONS
PreventMultipleEntrys = barssince(change(strategy.position_size)) > 10

BuySignal = Macd1x > 0 and Macd4x > 0 and PreventMultipleEntrys
SellSignal = Macd1x < 0 and Macd4x < 0

strategy.entry(id="Enter Long", long=true, when=BuySignal)
strategy.entry(id="Enter Short", long=false, when=SellSignal)
```

So I get both LONG and SHORT trade entries here.
But, when I add the `PreventMultipleEntrys` to my sell signal aswell, everything stops working. I dont get any buy or sell signals but still no error in the compiler?

Can someone smart help me here with this wierd error?
Here is the NONE working code:

```
//@version=4
strategy("Test script", overlay=true, pyramiding=100)
process_orders_on_close=true

// FACTOR 1X MACD
fastMA = round(12*1)
slowMA = round(26*1)
signal = round(9*1)
[Macd1x,_,Hist] = macd(close[0], fastMA, slowMA, signal)

// FACTOR 4X MACD
fastMA4x = round(12*4)
slowMA4x = round(26*4)
signal4x = round(9*4)
[Macd4x,_,_] = macd(close[0], fastMA4x, slowMA4x, signal4x)

// TRADE CONDITIONS
PreventMultipleEntrys = barssince(change(strategy.position_size)) > 10

BuySignal = Macd1x > 0 and Macd4x > 0 and PreventMultipleEntrys
SellSignal = Macd1x < 0 and Macd4x < 0 and PreventMultipleEntrys //This line makes everything stop working

strategy.entry(id="Enter Long", long=true, when=BuySignal)
strategy.entry(id="Enter Short", long=false, when=SellSignal)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses distinct logic to prevent early entries for longs and shorts. The problem with the way your code was written is that a first trade could never occur to get things going because a first change in position size 10 bars ago never happened:

```
//@version=4
strategy("Test script", overlay=true, pyramiding=100)
process_orders_on_close=true

// FACTOR 1X MACD
fastMA = round(12*1)
slowMA = round(26*1)
signal = round(9*1)
[Macd1x,_,Hist] = macd(close[0], fastMA, slowMA, signal)

// FACTOR 4X MACD
fastMA4x = round(12*4)
slowMA4x = round(26*4)
signal4x = round(9*4)
[Macd4x,_,_] = macd(close[0], fastMA4x, slowMA4x, signal4x)

// TRADE CONDITIONS
PreventMultipleLongEntries = sum(change(strategy.position_size) > 0 ? 1 : 0, 10) == 0
PreventMultipleShortEntries = sum(change(strategy.position_size) < 0 ? 1 : 0, 10) == 0

BuySignal = Macd1x > 0 and Macd4x > 0 and PreventMultipleLongEntries
SellSignal = Macd1x < 0 and Macd4x < 0 and PreventMultipleShortEntries

strategy.entry(id="Enter Long", long=true, when=BuySignal)
strategy.entry(id="Enter Short", long=false, when=SellSignal)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help. You are a legend!