# strategy.position_size is not counting trades that open & close within the same candle

Tags: pine-script

After a trade is closed/exited, regardless if was successful or not, I want to wait 5 minutes before getting into any new trades.

I am using '**strategy.position_size**' to check the previous 5 bars. If all previous 5 bars have been nil trades, only then can a new trade begin.

This line appears to do what I need:

BarsBack = sum(abs(change(strategy.position_size)) > 0 ? 1 : 0, 5) == 0

*(thanks to [Entry is not working when using barssince(change(strategy.position_size)) > 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63945371/entry-is-not-working-when-using-barssincechangestrategy-position-size-10) for the idea)*

BUT, if a trade opened and closed within the same bar, '**strategy.position_size**' does not register it as a trade. It considers it flat, zero, and therefore, if a new opportunity presents itself in the next candle, the strategy will enter, without waiting 5 minutes.

Note:

- I run this strategy on the 1min timeframe
- In the code below I have used the fixed amount "5", but in my real code I use an input variable, so I can change it in testing.

Any help is appreciated as it's doing my head in. Cheers.

```
BarsBack = sum(abs(change(strategy.position_size)) > 0 ? 1 : 0, 5) == 0

CurrentTrade = strategy.position_size == 0  // check if no open trades

if CurrentTrade
    if EMASpreadLongActive and CrossLowestLong and timeframe.isminutes
        strategy.entry("CONTBreakLongActive", strategy.long, qty = LotSize, when=BarsBack)
        strategy.exit("LongExit","CONTBreakLongActive", comment="Exit CONT Long",profit = ProfitTarget, loss = StopLoss)
        EMASpreadLongActive := false     // resetting
        CrossLowestLong := false         // resetting

    if EMASpreadShortActive and CrossHighestShort and timeframe.isminutes
        strategy.entry("CONTBreakShortActive", strategy.short, qty = LotSize, when=BarsBack)
        strategy.exit("ShortExit","CONTBreakShortActive",comment="Exit CONT Short", profit = ProfitTarget, loss = StopLoss)
        EMASpreadShortActive := false    // resetting
        CrossHighestShort := false       // resetting
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found two ways to resolve my issue.

1st, thanks to Paul Mendes, a simple method:

```
var wait = 0.
wait := change(strategy.closed_trades) ? time + (5*(60000)) : wait

if time >= wait and buy_condition
  strategy.entry....
```

2nd, again thanks to Paul for finding it at pinecoders.com.
This one is rather complicated though.
https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-implement-a-time-delay-between-orders

Cheers